# bind shared_ptr::reset - no matching overloaded function found

Tags: c++, boost, bind, shared-ptr

the following code snippet worked in Visual Studio 2005 (with boost 1.34) but it fails to compile in Visual Studio 2015 (with boost 1.62) saying that "error C2672: 'boost::bind': no matching overloaded function found"

Am I missing something here?

Thank you!

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr< int > SProxySharedPtr;
SProxySharedPtr    m_sptr_proxy;

auto a = boost::bind(&SProxySharedPtr::reset, &m_sptr_proxy);
```

Comment: Could you please share `SProxySharedPtr::reset` function? Is it callable without a parameter?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply :)

Comment: SProxySharedPtr is typedef ( typedef boost::shared_ptr< int > SProxySharedPtr;). So its essentially same as boost::shared_ptr<int>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`boost::shared_ptr<.>::reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#reset) is an overloaded member function. As a consequence, you have to designate explicitly which overload you want to use:

```
auto a = boost::bind(static_cast<void(SProxySharedPtr::*)()>(&SProxySharedPtr::reset), &m_sptr_proxy);
```

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!! (I wonder how it worked before :) ) For those who are experiencing this issue, please see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.troubleshooting.binding_an_overloaded_function

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use GCC but saw similar errors. The only way I can get it compile is to subclass boost::shared_ptr as below (but maybe this is not what you are asking for):

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> SProxySharedPtr;

struct Bar : SProxySharedPtr {
    void reset() {
        SProxySharedPtr::reset();
    }
};

int main()
{   
    const Bar m_sptr_proxy;
    boost::bind(&Bar::reset, &m_sptr_proxy);
}
```